# How to make Azure AD use SAML2

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I want to be able to use Azure AD with SAML2

To my understanding, the Azure AD will work as the IdP while I will host the STS myself

I have already set my application up to use Azure AD and SAML on their own. However, combining the two seems to cross some wires.

In my application's web.config, I have the following XML, which has worked with SAML:

```
  <sustainsys.saml2 entityId="https://saml-dc.qa.mycompany.com/Saml2/Acs" expectSignatureInXml="false" returnUrl="https://saml-dc.qa.mycompany.com" minIncomingSigningAlgorithm="SHA256" authenticateRequestSigningBehavior="Never">
<metadata cacheDuration="0:0:42" validDuration="7.12:00:00" wantAssertionsSigned="false">
  <requestedAttributes>
    <add name="Minimal" />
  </requestedAttributes>
</metadata>
<identityProviders>
  <add entityId="https://sts.windows.net/86e70697-498c-45e7-862a-c66e65ed3864/" signOnUrl="https://login.microsoftonline.com/86e70697-498c-45e7-862a-c66e65ed3864/saml2" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="false" binding="HttpRedirect" loadMetadata="true" metadataLocation="https://login.microsoftonline.com/86e70697-498c-45e7-862a-c66e65ed3864/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml?appid=9a8b9faf-9f86-4e98-806c-9c210642edec">
    <!--signingCertificate storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" findValue="myThumbprint" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" /-->
  </add>
</identityProviders>
```

I get the following error when logging in:

> AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'https://saml-dc.qa.MyCompany.com/Saml2/Acs' was not found in the directory '86e70697-498c-45e7-862a-c66e65ed3864'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant

The "MyCompany" is a substitute

I'm still quite new to using SAML - but I do grasp the basics of it. Please feel free to correct me, if what I'm stating above is unclear or erroneous.

Comment: AFAIK Azure AD does not support custom IdPs. Only MSA and Google personal accounts are supported for federation. (well and on-prem AD via ADFS) You should look into Azure AD B2C which does allow you to specify custom policies that allow you to use custom IdPs.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will look into this.

Comment: Are you looking to sign in to Azure AD with your service (Azure AD is the relying party), or are you looking to sign in to your app with Azure AD (the app is the relying party)?

Comment: @Poiar - Were you able to find a resolution for this? I'm running into the exact same problem and could use some guidance.

Comment: @Casey - I was relaying the information for a colleague of mine, who actually solved it. I'm not exactly sure how - but it seemed like the problem was due to the fact that the site I was trying to connect to, wasn't externally available. I hope this helps - if not, then I might be able to give you some info on Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can via a custom SAML connection.

Here's an [example](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-adfs-and-azure-active-directory-via-the-custom-saml-connection-e0fc522b71ca) using ADFS.

Comment: While I'm not exactly certain that your guide necessarily will fix the issue I had, it would have been worth gold when I researched this issue. Therefore I'm making your answer as the correct one.